# Cannot use fill between and clip markers

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

In the `groupplot` environment I need to use `fill between` two paths and one of these path have markers that are on the axes. I want to clip these markers but it causes a problem with `fill between`, as the first path is then considered as empty.

How can I clip markers and use `fill between`?

A MWE is given below. To see the problem clearly, you can toggle the commented line `clip marker paths=true,` on and off. If it is uncommented, the problem is here.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, pgfplots.groupplots}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1}, scale only axis,
%   clip marker paths=true,
    axis on top=true]

    % Plot main figure (a)
    \nextgroupplot[scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=100,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=550]

    \addplot[name path = pathA, color=blue, mark=square*] coordinates {(0,250)(100,450)};
    \path[name path = pathAxis] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:100,0);
    \addplot [gray!30] fill between[of = pathA and pathAxis, soft clip = {domain=20:50}];

    \nextgroupplot[scale only axis, restrict y to domain=190:240]

    \end{groupplot}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As a workaround, you could just add a path only for the fill `\addplot[name path = pathA,draw=none,no marks,forget plot] coordinates {(0,250)(100,450)};` and one for the marks and plot, `\addplot[color=blue, mark=square*] coordinates {(0,250)(100,450)};`.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly for my purpose!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a work around. You add the plot twice, once invisibly to have something that can be used for the fill, and once "for real". (I have experimented a bit with clips and so on, but none of what popped up was really more elegant than this work around, so I post it. Obviously I do hope that there is a more elegant solution.)

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, pgfplots.groupplots}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1}, scale only axis,
    axis on top=true]

    % Plot main figure (a)
    \nextgroupplot[scale only axis,clip marker paths=true,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=100,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=550]

    \addplot[color=blue, mark=square*] coordinates {(0,250)(100,450)};
    \addplot[name path = pathA,draw=none,no marks,forget plot] coordinates {(0,250)(100,450)};
    \path[name path = pathAxis] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:100,0);
    \addplot [gray!30] fill between[of = pathA and pathAxis, soft clip = {domain=20:50}];

    \nextgroupplot[scale only axis, restrict y to domain=190:240]
    \end{groupplot}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]